# Injectivity, Projectivity, and $P$-injectivity of Localization

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules, projective-module, injective-module

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unity.

> I have read that if $M$ is an injective $R$-module, then $S^{-1}M$ is not necessarily an injective $S^{-1}R$-module. I need an example...

Does last statement true for $P$-injectivity and projectivity?

Comment: What is P-injectivity?

Comment: $P$-injectivity means if $f: aR\rightarrow M$, then there exist an extension $g:R\rightarrow M$ such that $g=f$ on $aR$, where $aR$ is principal ideal generated by an element $a$ .

Comment: For the first part, essentially answered in the comments on [Localization of an injective module is also injective](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/265417/localization-of-an-injective-module-is-also-injective), true in the Noetherian case but with references to counterexamples that are non-Noetherian.

Answer (score 2):

The localisation of a projective module is projective since a projective module is a direct summand of a free module, and localisation preserves direct summands and freeness.

A counter-example for injective modules was built by E. Dade in 1981, and you can find it in his paper [Localization of injective modules](http://www.google.fr/url?url=http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0021869381902131&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&sa=U&ved=0CB8QFjABahUKEwj1gs26wJrHAhUGuxQKHYyUAJM&sig2=7EJk1Qh5m2WW60hYNFO4EQ&usg=AFQjCNEZrkMPV4ozzxyB6eveqz0sjNX7zQ), in which he also gives a sufficient condition for this property to be true.

This condition consists of the following $3$ subconditions on the ring $R$ and the multiplicative set $S$:

1. $R$ is a *coherent* ring.
2. For any finitely generated ideal $I$  of $R$ and $s\in S$, the chain:
   $$I\subset (I:s)\subseteq (I:s^2)\subseteq (I:s^3)\subseteq\cdots$$
   stabilises.
3. Ideals of $R$  are countably generated.

In particular, it is true for *noetherian rings*.

Comment: What about the case for $P$- injectivity .

Comment: user26857 counterexample for the statement I wrote is not true always. I thought there is an easy example , but according to Dade's paper, it is not easy ..

Comment: If it was found in 1981, while the notion of injectivity dates back to the 40s, it clearly is not a trivial question! For p-injectivity, I know nothing about it. If the ring is a domain, it seems to be the same notion as divisibility?